# Sending JSON file to Server to use it in D3.js in R

Tags: json, r

I have a big data frame of this format:

```
House   space   type        ID  less than 18    18 to 23    Greather than 23
1   Livingroom  Temperature 1   0             29.44004742   70.55995258
1   Hallway     temperature 1   14.59211237   61.59805511   23.80983252
1   Bedroom     temperature 1   1.683093749   60.63394348   37.68296277
2   Livingroom  Temperature 2   17.16494111   49.53457447   33.30048442
2   Hallway     temperature 2   36.3833926    49.56992189   14.04668551
2   Bedroom     temperature 2   39.74861892   53.78744108   6.463939993
```

I used the following code to convert it to a json object:

```
library(RJSONIO)
houses<- by(data, list(data$House), function(x) {

  outer_template <- '{"id":"House_%s","condition":[%s]}'

  inner_template <- '{"type":"%s","segment":{"Less than 18":%s, "18-25":%s , "Greater than 25":%s},"space":"%s"}'

  condition <- paste0(apply(x, 1, function(y) {sprintf(inner_template,tolower(y["type"]), y["less.than.18"], y["X18.to.23"],y["Greather.than.23"], tolower(y["space"]))}), collapse=",\n")
  sprintf(outer_template, x$House[1], condition)

}) 
house_json <-(sprintf("[%s]", paste0(houses, collapse=",\n")))

exportJson <- toJSON(house_json, method="C" )
```

I created the JSON object and then saved the file to my system as `test.json`. Now I want to send this as JSON file to database server to directly use in some d3.js code. I wrote the following code for this:

```
writeLines(exportJson, "test.json")
file <- 'C:/.../Documents/test.json'
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(file), collapse=",\n"))
json_data
```

This code is not working for me, it returns the `json_data` output with ',\' characters. like:

```
"[{\"id\":\"House_1\",\"condition\":[{\"type\":\"temperature\",\"segment\":{\"Less than 18\": 0.000000, \"18-25\":29.44005 , \"Greater than 25\":70.55995},\"space\":\"livingroom\"},\n{\"type\":\"temperature\",\"segment\":{\"Less than 18\":14.592112, \"18-25\":61.59806 , \"Greater than 25\":23.80983},\"space\":\"hallway\"},\n{\"type\":\"temperature\",\"segment\":{\"Less than 18\": 1.683094, \"18-25\":60.63394 , \"Greater than 25\":37.68296},\"space\":\"bedroom\"}]},\n and so on...
```

I have tried almost 10 different methods to remove these extra characters(, and backslash) but nothing is working for me. Its kind of disappointment for me. Any of your help will be much much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: I need the JSON format like this:

```
{ 
    "id":"House_1", 
    "condition":
      [ 
        { "type":"temperature", 
          "segment":{"Less than 18": 0.000000, "18-25":29.44005 , "Greater than 25":70.55995},
          "unit":"day",
          "space":"livingroom"
        },
        { "type":"temperature", 
          "segment":{"Less than 18":14.592112, "18-25":61.59806 , "Greater than 25":23.80983},
          "unit":"day",
          "space":"hallway"
        },
        { "type":"temperature", 
          "segment":{"Less than 18": 1.683094, "18-25":60.63394 , "Greater than 25":37.68296},
          "unit":"day",
          "space":"bedroom"
        } 
      ] 
  },
  { 
    "id":"House_2", 
    "condition":
      [ 
        { "type":"temperature", 
          "segment":{"Less than 18":17.16494, "18-25":49.53457 , "Greater than 25":33.30048},
          "unit":"day",
          "space":"livingroom"
        },
        { "type":"temperature", 
          "segment":{"Less than 18":36.38339, "18-25":49.56992 , "Greater than 25":14.04669},
          "unit":"day",
          "space":"hallway"
        },
        { "type":"temperature", 
          "segment":{"Less than 18":39.74862, "18-25":53.78744 , "Greater than 25": 6.46394},
          "unit":"day",
          "space":"bedroom"
        } 
      ] 
  } and so on...
```

Comment: You are creating a string (text) that looks like JSON then asking to convert it to JSON - hence your results. Instead simply call toJSON(data) and look at the output.

Comment: @Cyrille Actually I need a customized format of JSON file which I added in the questions as an edit. for this format I needed to define the format first. simply using toJSON doesn't give the required result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually work on generating the R equivalent of the JSON in list format, then use `toJSON` to do the transformation. In your case, the list would look something like:

```
library("RJSONIO")
df <- read.table(textConnection("House   space   type        ID  'less than 18'    '18 to 23'    'Greather than 23'
1   Livingroom  Temperature 1   0             29.44004742   70.55995258
                                1   Hallway     temperature 1   14.59211237   61.59805511   23.80983252
                                1   Bedroom     temperature 1   1.683093749   60.63394348   37.68296277
                                2   Livingroom  Temperature 2   17.16494111   49.53457447   33.30048442
                                2   Hallway     temperature 2   36.3833926    49.56992189   14.04668551
                                2   Bedroom     temperature 2   39.74861892   53.78744108   6.463939993"),
                  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
output <- list()
for(id in unique(df$ID)){
  tmp <- df[df$ID==id, ]
  row_list <- list()
  for(row in 1:nrow(tmp)){
     row_list <- append(row_list, 
                        list(
                          list("type"=tmp$type[row],
                             "segment"=list("Less than 18"=tmp$less.than.18[row],
                                            "18-25"=tmp$X18.to.23[row],
                                            "Greater than 25"=tmp$Greather.than.23[row]
                               ),
                               "unit"="day",
                               "space"=tmp$space[row]
                          )
                        )
     )
  }
  output <- append(output, list(list("id"=paste0("House_", id), 
                                "condition" = row_list)))
}
```

This creates JSON that looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id" : "House_1",
        "condition" : [
            {
                "type" : "Temperature",
                "segment" : {
                    "Less than 18" : 0,
                    "18-25" : 29.44,
                    "Greater than 25" : 70.56
                },
                "unit" : "day",
                "space" : "Livingroom"
            },
            {
                "type" : "temperature",
                "segment" : {
                    "Less than 18" : 14.592,
                    "18-25" : 61.598,
                    "Greater than 25" : 23.81
                },
                "unit" : "day",
                "space" : "Hallway"
            },
            {
                "type" : "temperature",
                "segment" : {
                    "Less than 18" : 1.6831,
                    "18-25" : 60.634,
                    "Greater than 25" : 37.683
                },
                "unit" : "day",
                "space" : "Bedroom"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : "House_2",
        "condition" : [
            {
                "type" : "Temperature",
                "segment" : {
                    "Less than 18" : 17.165,
                    "18-25" : 49.535,
                    "Greater than 25" : 33.3
                },
                "unit" : "day",
                "space" : "Livingroom"
            },
            {
                "type" : "temperature",
                "segment" : {
                    "Less than 18" : 36.383,
                    "18-25" : 49.57,
                    "Greater than 25" : 14.047
                },
                "unit" : "day",
                "space" : "Hallway"
            },
            {
                "type" : "temperature",
                "segment" : {
                    "Less than 18" : 39.749,
                    "18-25" : 53.787,
                    "Greater than 25" : 6.4639
                },
                "unit" : "day",
                "space" : "Bedroom"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You just have to do the work to get the dataframe into the appropriate list format, then `toJSON` makes valid JSON out of it...

Comment: I have a big data file, how we can convert your logic to a function to apply on the whole data frame?

Comment: I've updated the code above with a loop to create the list structure. It's kinda ugly, but it gets the job done...